# Как передавать oauth токен и какие-то параметры через curl -x post

Tags: post, curl, oauth

Надо передавать токен через curl -X Post https://url api?параметры=значение какое-то и плюс к этому нужен oauth token.

Чтобы получить доступ к api, нужно через командную строку делать curl -x post https:// урл какой то и плюс oauth токен, который создали через Яндекс. И вот не понятно как oauth токен указывать. Может кто-нибудь сталкивался с таким?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: прочитайте, как передаются параметры в [url](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#%D0%A1%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D1%80%D0%B0_URL)

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -X POST https://urlapi -H "Authorization: OAuth oauth_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, oauth_client_id=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" -d '{"данные запроса"}'
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]